Dump python memory in search of variables
I am in the process of learning Python and I got intrigued by the memory management topic: heap, stack, garbage collector etc.
So, for a simple program like:
a=5
print(id(a))
b=2
print(id(b))
c=a+b
print(id(c))

I'd like to be able to watch the memory used by this process, its content and structure.
I found out that I have to do a dump of the python process while running, and I was able to do it on my linux laptop.
Then I opened the resulting file with a HEX reader and was able to find the variables searching for the value and variable name.
I'd like to understand instead how to find the variable based on its memory address that I presume comes from the id() function.
I am also interested to understand how to see "line" between stack and heap.
I know that it sounds overkilling but I'm just curious to see how this whole thing works and then maybe try with lists and dictionaries.
Hope I explained everything properly.
Thanks to whoever would like to help.

You're using the wrong tools for this. Open the memory dump in the context of a debugging session and the debugger will ensure that the exact memory layout of the original process is restored. You can then quite literally take the output of id() as a pointer value and cast it to Py_Object*.

Thank @Botje can you please explain or address me to a tutorial? I'm still at the beginning and I don't understand the steps you are mentioning.
For example what do you mean with "open the dump in the context of a debugging session"?
Thanks for understanding

You can pass a core dump to the debugger (gdb or lldb) and it will load the core dump as if you started the program from the debugger. You cannot execute anything but you can still inspect the entire memory with the correct mappings in place

One of the things you still have to learn about Python: It abstracts the memory away from you, by design. So, if you want to watch the memory directly to debug a simple program without any memory related code that will be written in another language like C, then you are doing it wrong.
